# Why addSubview doesn't show?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I wanted to programmatically add `myView` to parent view. But it doesn't show up on screen. What's wrong with the code?

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic,weak) UIView *myView;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize myView = _myView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect viewRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100);
    self.myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];
    self.myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:self.myView];
}
```

Comment: try `@property (nonatomic,strong) UIView *myView;`

Comment: Thanks,that works. But I wonder why? Setting property to strong makes myView is retained twice, both by controller (self) and self.view. Is that correct? Why weak don't work?

Comment: NO, it's the only subview. It seems that property is indeed relevant, because changing weak to strong fix the problem.

Comment: Alright, there's some interesting magic: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9747451/792677

Comment: property attribute tells the compiler how your object be treated. here is a link that has good information regarding weak and strong. http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1

Comment: Thanks @A-Live, that's exactly the explanation I need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace

```
@property (nonatomic,weak) UIView *myView;
```

with

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *myView;
```

and it should work :)

Answer (score 2):

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

UIView *myView;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect viewRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100);

    myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];

    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [self.view addSubview:myView];
}
```

try this it will work…