# addSubView not adding subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api

I have an app that should display a Youtube video and I'm using the [Youtube ios helper API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper).

I have a subclass of UITabBarController that is used to present two youtube videos and the UITabBarController is inside a NavController and is pushed to from a UITableViewController. So the setup looks like

[NAVController] -- relationship --> [UITableViewController] -- push --> [UITabBarController] -- relationship --> [CustomViewController]

Now my CustomViewController.h looks like:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "YTPlayerView.h"

@interface CustomViewController : UIViewController<YTPlayerViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) YTPlayerView *youtubeView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *videoID;

@end
```

and my .m file has

```
#import "CustomViewController.h"
#import "YTPlayerView.h"

@interface CustomViewController ()

@end

@implementation CustomViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.youtubeView.delegate = self;

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    self.youtubeView.frame = self.view.frame;

    self.youtubeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [self.view addSubview:self.youtubeView];

    NSLog(@"Subviews %lu", (unsigned long)[self.view.subviews count]);
    NSLog(@"Subviews %@", self.views.subviews);

    BOOL b = [self.youtubeView loadWithVideoId:self.videoID];
    NSLog(@"Loaded? %d", b);
    [self.youtubeView playVideo];        
}
```

What I end up with is a navigation bar at the top (as it should be), a tab bar at the bottom (as it should be), but with a blue background instead of a red background (and needless to say, no Youtube video loads). When I run this, it prints

Subviews 0
Subviews (
)
Loaded? 0

Clearly the addSubView: call is not working.

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747015/why-is-addsubview-not-retaining-the-view), but it didn't help.

(For those unfamiliar with the youtube ios helper library:

> The youtube-ios-player-helper is an open source library that helps you embed a YouTube iframe player into an iOS application. The library creates a UIWebView and a bridge between your application’s Objective-C code and the YouTube player’s JavaScript code, thereby allowing the iOS application to control the YouTube player.

(Using iOS 7 and Xcode 5.1)

Comment: Where are you initializing: `self.youtubeView` ? aka: `self.youtubeView =[YTPlayerView alloc]init];`

Comment: Weird. That didn't work for me before, but now seems to... Thanks! As a followup, in the YT docs, it doesn't show initialization. Is an IBOutlet automatically alloc'd and initialized?

Comment: Yes, an IBOutlet is automatic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I don't see that you're using an IBOutlet, I believe you need to initialize the `self.youtubeView`:

```
self.youtubeView = [[YTPlayerView alloc]init];

self.youtubeView.delegate = self;

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

self.youtubeView.frame = self.view.frame;

self.youtubeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[self.view addSubview:self.youtubeView];
```

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube api isn't the problem here, UINavigation controller and UITabBarController just dont play nicely together. What you should do instead is make a view controller to handle the tabbar instead of a UITabBarController. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576764/tab-bar-controller-inside-a-navigation-controller-or-sharing-a-navigation-root) shows some insight on how to get it done.

Comment: Haha, it seems that troop231's answer solved it for you, but if you have troubles with the frames this should help

Comment: They seem to be playing nicely for me. What doesnt work well?

Comment: Sorry, I meant pushing views. I had trouble with it in my previous apps, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/576764/tab-bar-controller-inside-a-navigation-controller-or-sharing-a-navigation-root

It might have been me just doing something weird, though :P

Comment: I used Storyboard segues and it works fine. I'm surprised it doesnt work using pushViewController:animated:. iOS often has that weirdness